# Upgrading from Python 2 > 3 - Boto's `receive_messages` blocks unrelated threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, boto3, amazon-sqs

While working on upgrading some code from Python 2.7 to 3.7, I found that boto SQS client's `receive_message` function will block other threads while it's waiting. The following is a rough example:

```py
sqs_client = boto_session.client('sqs')

def dequeue_message():
    logger.info('dequeue_message: BEGIN')
    time.sleep(0.5)  # Allow the other thread to start sleeping
    logger.info('dequeue_message: START POLLING')
    res = sqs_client.receive_message(
        QueueUrl=queue_url,
        MaxNumberOfMessages=1,
        VisibilityTimeout=1,
        WaitTimeSeconds=10,
    )  # This will only block if there are no messages available
    logger.info('dequeue_message: DONE {}'.format(res))

def just_wait():
    logger.info('just_wait: BEGIN')
    start_time = time.time()
    time.sleep(2)
    logger.info('just_wait: DONE (expected 2, actual {})'.format(int(time.time() - start_time)))

wait_task = threading.Thread(target=just_wait)
dequeue_task = threading.Thread(target=dequeue_message)
wait_task.start()
dequeue_task.start()
wait_task.join()
dequeue_task.join()
```

In python 2, the `just_wait` thread waits 2 seconds and returns. However, in Python 3, the `just_wait` thread ends up waiting 10 seconds (the wait time on `receive_message`) before returning, presumably somehow "blocked" by the call to `receive_message`.

The Python 3 behavior is a bit of a problem. **What could cause it to hang like that?**

I should also note that this is in a much larger tech stack that I'm not 100% familiar with. There may be other libraries or functionality running in the background that I'm not currently aware of.

Relevant library versions: `boto3@1.7.84`, `botocore@1.10.84`

Comment: Wanted to post a comment in case this helps anyone in the future - I _think_ this might have been due to an SSL configuration option that prevented it from being multi-threaded. Unfortunately, I can't verify the original code to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiprocessing as a workaround.

Create a separate process to collect messages from AWS SQS queue into a multiprocessing Queue:

```
import multiprocessing
from queue import Empty

def logs_queue_producer(logs_queue: multiprocessing.Queue):
    # Get a polling queue
    sqs_resource = boto3.resource('sqs')
    queue_name = f'LogsQueue'
    aws_logs_queue = sqs_resource.get_queue_by_name(QueueName=queue_name)

    while True:
        messages = aws_logs_queue.receive_messages(MaxNumberOfMessages=10, WaitTimeSeconds=1)

        while len(messages) > 0:
            for message in messages:
                logs_queue.put(message.body)
                message.delete()

            messages = aws_logs_queue.receive_messages(MaxNumberOfMessages=10, WaitTimeSeconds=1)

logs_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
process = multiprocessing.Process(target=logs_queue_producer,
                                  args=(logs_queue, ))
process.start()
```

In the main process, create a consumer function:

```
def logs_queue_consumer(self):
    while True:
        try:
            message_body = logs_queue.get_nowait()
            # TODO Add your code
        except Empty:
            pass
```

The boto3 sqs Message itself can't be pickled, so I collect only a message body. It's enough for my needs. If you need a whole message, you can try jsonifying it.